# NoSuchMethodException when using reflection with Spring JPARespository Methods (eg: findByName)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying implement multiple filters with **JPA Query Methods** offered by **Spring Data JPA**.

Dynamic filter
eg:  `findByNameContainingCreatedAtBefore`

(eg: `findByName`) and I used Java Reflection to get a method from **JPA Repository** and invoke dynamically.

```
Method method = institutionRepository.getClass().getMethod("findByName", String.class);
```

But the above line throws `NoSuchMethodException`.

Are there any ways to fix the above issue?

Comment: Please add your actual repository. Also why reflection? What do you try to achieve that Spring Data doesn't already achieve for you?

Comment: I'm trying design a dynamic filter.

Comment: And why would you need reflection for that? Instead use predicates which is much easier and doesn't require reflection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Predicates and i'll take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I bet there is no `findByName` in your source code and you're expecting to see the method generated by the spring-data-jpa. This will not happen, because the method isn't added by spring to the repository itself, but to the proxy over that repository. That's why it has to be a bean - so that it can be wrapped by spring with a proxy to provide all the functionality.